# In which order does SQL Server apply filters - top down or bottom up (first to last or last to first)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, filter

When I write code I like to make sure I'm optimizing performance.  I would assume that this includes ordering the filters to have the heavy reducers (filter out lots of rows) at the top and the lighter reducers (filter out a few rows) at the bottom.

But when I have errors in my filters I have noticed that SQL Server first catches the errors in the filters at the bottom and then catches the errors in the filters at the top.  Does this mean that SQL Server processes filters from the bottom up?

For example (for clarity I'm the filter - with intentional typos - in the WHERE clause rather than the JOIN clause):

```
select
   l.Loan_Number
   ,l.Owner_First_Name
   ,l.Owner_Last_Name
   ,l.Street
   ,l.City
   ,l.State
   ,p.Balance
   ,p.Delinquency_Bucket
   ,p.Next_Due_Date
from
   Location l
   join Payments p on l.Account_Number = p.Account_Number
where
   l.OOOOOwner_Last_Name = 'Kostoryz' -- I assume this would reduce the most, so I put it first
   and p.DDDDelinquency = '90+' -- I assume this would reduce second most, so I put it second
   and l.SSSState <> 'WY' -- I assume this would reduce the least, so I put it last
```

Yet the first error SQL Server would return would be  ERROR - THERE IS NO COLUMN SSSState IN Location TABLE

The next error it would return would be ERROR - THERE IS NO COLUMN DDDDelinquency IN Payments TABLE

Does this mean that the State filter would be applied before the Delinquency filter and the Delinquency filter would be applied before the Last_Name filter?

Comment: The query will get compiled and the engine will determine which order to execute your where clause conditions in and which indexes to use. Order doesn't matter

Comment: Filters are applied in the order that the query engine thinks will provide the fastest result. Use CTRL-L to see the estimated query plan which will show you when filters are applied. Note the query plan can change from execution to execution. The actual order that you write them in makes very little difference.

Answer (score 3):

There are roughly three stages that happen, when a query is received in text form by the DBMS until you get its result.

1. The text is usually transformed into some internal format, the DBMS can easier work with.
2. From the internal format the DBMS tries to compute an optimal way of actual execution, you can think of it as a little program that is developed there.
3. That program is actually executed and the result is written somewhere (in the memory) you can fetch it from.

(These stages possibly can be divided in even smaller substages, but that level of detail isn't needed here, I guess.)

Now with that in mind, note that for one the errors you mention are emitted in stage 1, when the DBMS tries to bind actual objects in the DB and cannot find them. The query is far from execution at that point and the order that binding is done has got nothing to do with the order the filters are actually applied later. Additionally thereafter is stage 2. In order to find an optimal way of execution, the DBMS can and will reorder things (not necessarily only filters). So it usually doesn't matter how you ordered the filters or how the order of binding went. The DBMS will look at them and decide which one is better to be applied earlier and which one may wait until later.

Keep in mind, that SQL is a descriptive language. Rather than telling the machine what to do -- what we'd typically do when writing programs in imperative languages -- we describe what result we want and let the machine figure out how to calculate it and how to do this in the best possible way or at least a good way.

(Of course, that optimization may not always work a 100%. Sometimes there are some tricks in queries, that help the DBMS to find a better solution. But with a query of the kind you posted, any DBMS should cope pretty well in finding a good order to apply the filters no matter how you ordered them.)

Answer (score 2):

Before SQL Server attempts to run the query, it creates a Query Execution Plan (QEP).  The errors you are seeing are happening while the QEP is being built.  You cannot infer any information about the sequence of "filters" based on the order you get these errors.
Once you have provided a valid query, SQL Server will build a QEP and that will govern the operations it uses to satisfy the query.  The QEP will be based on many factors including what indexes and statistics are available on the table - though not usually the order that you specify conditions in the WHERE clause.  There are ways to do this, but it is usually not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

In Short, NO. The order of the filters don't matter.

At a high level, the query goes through multiple stages before execution. The stages are:

- **Parsing & Normalization** (where the syntax is checked and tables are validated)
- **Compilation & Optimization** (Where the code is compiled and optimized for execution)

In the Optimization stage, the table statistics, index statistics are checked to arrive at the optimal execution plan for executing the query. So, the filers are checked based on the statistics and are applied in order based on the statistics. So, the order of filters in the query DON'T MATTER. The column statistics DO MATTER.

[Read more on Stages of query execution](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/inside-sql-server-parse-compile-and-optimize)